# Как изменить цвет фона в приложении касанием на экран

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Нужно изменить цвет фона в приложении на рандомный касаясь любого места на экране. Пишу в студии на джаве.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально не понятно что значит "фон приложения". Макет экрана состоит из элементов, и хотелось бы уточнения какой именно элемент вы хотите изменить, так как возможно будет зависеть реализация. Во-вторых - определитесь с ЯП, а то Java и Kotlin оба хороши, но я думаю вы же можете сказать какой именно ЯП вы используете. Но в целом программно сделать можно так:

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

или через ресурсы приложения:

```
yourView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
```

но вам ведь нужен клик. Поэтому обрабатываем клик по элементу:

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              yourView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        }
    });
```

рандомный цвет получаем так:

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
yourView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

ну и наконец итоговый вариант:

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Random rnd = new Random(); 
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
    yourView.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
});
```

код выше как можно понять написан на Java, если ВСЕ-ТАКИ вам нужен Kotlin то просто вставьте это в активность/фрагмент и студия конвертирует.

**P.S.** *Пожалуйста когда задаете вопросы, пишете максимально доступным языком включая в вопрос всю информацию связанную с вашей проблемой. У вас не понятно где это происходит (активность/фрагмент) не понятно на каком языке вам это нужно, не понятно цвет чего именно вы хотите изменить, и тд и тп. Пожалуйста включайте в ваши вопросы больше подробностей и тогда вероятность его закрытия понизится, а вероятность того что вам ответят станет намного выше.*

Comment: я делал на джаве в разделе LinearLayout. Я правильно понял что вместо yourView нужно указывать LinearLayout. А еще у меня горит красным yourView, color и @Override

Comment: нужно добавить как переменную ваш виджет в класс активности, присвойте ей id и объявите ее в классе со значением. То есть yourView = findViewById(R.id.yourId) и дальше уже можно будет менять цвет